# Computer goes randomly into hybrid sleep

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I run Windows Vista on a HP TouchSmarttx2. In the last weeks the computer goes randomly into hybrid sleep even through electricity is plugged in and battery is full.
What could cause this behavior?

Comment: An application could be doing it for you.  Hell, it could be malware.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when you are working on it or when it is not used?

If it happens when the computer is not used go to Control Panel -> Power Setting and change the standby settings to never or a longer period of time.

Comment: It happens when I'm working and the power setting is that on Never/Never/Never/Never.

Comment: Check the windows log, it might give you a clue on what is initiating the sleep mode. Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Event Viewer